# TinyMCE content_css in Vue3 application

Tags: css, tinymce, vuejs3

I have TinyMCE implementation in Vue3 project according [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-vue-3-support/). Everything works fine. Now I would like to set up custom css for editor content. [Documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-css-and-custom-styles/) is clear for the classic web applications but I dont know how to do it for Vue3.

I have a tinymce-custom.css file in root assets folder. But dont know how to get the file to the TinyMCE init object.

This is the code for TinyMCE init object

```
tinyInit: {
    themes: "modern",
    entity_encoding: "raw",
    content_css: "/assets/tinymce-custom.css",  // This does not work. No error in log.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `content_css` configuration option expects a URL that is accessible at runtime in the browser that is loading TinyMCE.  If that path is not correct you would likely see a 404 error in the developer console when TinyMCE tries to load that URL.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

There is also a `content_style` attribute that can be used to pass a string of CSS directly into the configuration:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to save custom css file to the public folder and in the code use relative path to the root of the project like `/tinymce-custom.css`